# model about Formal format reply after examiner's amendment

Tags: response, allowability

I have received a Notice of Allowability for claims contained in an examiner's amendment, but I don't know the formal format to reply. I would be very grateful if someone can provide an example. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about paying an issue fee?  Did you get a Notice of Allowance?  One thing you could do is call the Examiner on the phone.  He/she will be familiar with your case.

Comment: Is there even a formal format to reply? Or a need to reply? Does the notice say anything about what you should do?